# why margin is given hardcoded in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, css

I am making image slider dynamically (don't want to use any `hard corded` value).I am able to make slider but I have two issue.

1. why I need `20px` more in `ul` width .is there any way not to use this hard corded value .

   ```
    $('#list').css('width',$('#list').find('.box').length*li_Width+20)
   ```

   - why some part `left` of box when user click `next` button.Example when user click on `next` button it show `next` box without showing any part **(green box)** ..But when user click on next button it show some part of`blue` box why ? why it is not slide fully ? If user click again next button it show again more part of red why ?

here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/t2yOFkO1QBWOVLFreiXm?p=preview

// Code goes here

```
$(function(){

  var li_Width =$('#list').find('.box:first').outerWidth(true);
  // why 20 pixel is hardcorded
  $('#list').css('width',$('#list').find('.box').length*li_Width+20)
 $('#next').click(function(){
  $('#list').css('margin-left',addToMarginLeft($('#list'),-li_Width))
 })
 $('#pre').click(function(){
    $('#list').css('margin-left',addToMarginLeft($('#list'),li_Width))
 })

 function addToMarginLeft(elem, pixels) {
    var ml = parseFloat(elem.css('margin-left'));
    elem.animate({
    'margin-left': (ml + pixels) + 'px'
    },1000)

  }

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is due to css `inline-block` white space between element .
which cause some extra space , so that why you've got to add 20px .

There are several method to work around this last : comenting between li or just setting font size  to 0 like bellow :

```
ul {
  ...
  font-size: 0
}
```

bellow you find working snippet :

I've just added some jquery code to prevent miltiple click button which trigger another annimation before the last one is being finished :

```js
// Code goes here
$(function() {

  var li_Width = $('#list').find('.box:first').outerWidth(true);
  // 20 px removed !!!
  $('#list').css('width', $('#list').find('.box').length * li_Width)

  $('#next').click(function() {
    if( !$("#list").is(":animated") )
    $('#list').css('margin-left', addToMarginLeft($('#list'), -li_Width))
  })
  $('#pre').click(function() {
    if( !$("#list").is(":animated") )
    $('#list').css('margin-left', addToMarginLeft($('#list'), li_Width))
  })

  function addToMarginLeft(elem, pixels) {
    var ml = parseFloat(elem.css('margin-left'));
    elem.animate({
      'margin-left': (ml + pixels) + 'px'
    }, 1000)

  }

})
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 1300px;
  /* here you set font to 0 for extra space */
  font-size: 0
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#list {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <button id="next">next</button>
  <button id="pre">pre</button>
  <ul id="list">
    <li class="box green">
    </li>
    <li class="box blue">
    </li>
    <li class="box red">
    </li>
    <li class="box yellow">
    </li>
    <li class="box pink">
    </li>
    <li class="box orange">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: quest gotta up ++ .